# Combine 2 established calls by using B2BUA

Tags: c#, sip, voip, lync, ucma

In a UCMA application, I want to bridge two already established calls, by using a B2B call to remain in control of both calls.

Does anyone know how you can bridge two established calls through a B2BUA of UCMA 4.0?

As far as I know, B2BUA needs incoming-idle state scenario. In my scenario I'm having established-established scenario. I'm sure I could turn one of the calls as incoming state, by initiating a Self-transfer. But I can't figure out how to turn the 2nd call into a state that I can use for the B2B-bridging.

Any ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into UCMA "call replacement"? Rather than transferring to a new destination, you send a "REPLACES" header. The mandatory Greenlee blog on the subject is here: http://blog.greenl.ee/2011/08/20/switching-lync-call-participants-with-ucma/

This in combination with a self transfer on one of the two sides might be able to resolve your problems.

In case it doesn't, you might have to put both calls into a conference.

Comment: Currently I have a call replacement like written in the blog, but it leaves me without further call control (avCall.BeginTransfer(secondAvCAll, null, TransferCB, avCall); I'm not sure on how this combination with a self-transfer on one or both sides works. Could you please provide an example?

Comment: Sorry I have no example, I was just thinking aloud ;) I expected the call replacement to take a call in 'incoming/ringing' state, meaning you'd have to self-transfer one leg of one B2B, and then make a call replacement on the other leg of the other B2B with the incoming self-transfer.